# how to turn string into nested list with elements separated with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

I have a string which looks like this:

```
'(a (b (c d e f)) g)'
```

I want to turn it into such a nested list:

```
['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], 'g']
```

I used this function:

```
def tree_to_list(text, left=r'[(]', right=r'[)]', sep=r','):
    pat = r'({}|{}|{})'.format(left, right, sep)
    tokens = re.split(pat, text)    
    stack = [[]]
    for x in tokens:
        if not x or re.match(sep, x): continue
        if re.match(left, x):
            stack[-1].append([])
            stack.append(stack[-1][-1])
        elif re.match(right, x):
            stack.pop()
            if not stack:
                raise ValueError('error: opening bracket is missing')
        else:
            stack[-1].append(x)
    if len(stack) > 1:
        print(stack)
        raise ValueError('error: closing bracket is missing')
    return stack.pop()
```

But result is not what i expected. There are no commas among strings:

```
['a', ['b', ['c' 'd' 'e' 'f']], 'g']
```

Could you please help me with that

Answer (score 5):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
import re
data = '(a (b (c d e f)) g)'
def group(d):
    a = next(d, ')')
    if a != ')':
        yield list(group(d)) if a == '(' else a
        yield from group(d)
print(next(group(iter(re.findall(r'\w+|[()]', data)))))
```

Output:

```
['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], 'g']
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but I would recommend just to iterate the string directly and add handling for whitespace, rather than using regex.  +1 anyway.

Comment: this function removes dots. for example if i have words instead of letters('07.45'  instead of 'a') it will turn '07.45' into '07'  '45'

Comment: @EdgarZakharyan Simply adjust the regex: `re.findall(r'[\w\.]+|[()]', data)`.

Comment: Nice, clean concise code. Care to add some comments to explain how the function works a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 3):

Using string replacements to turn the input into the string with the desired Python value, and `literal_eval` to turn it into the value itself:

```
>>> import ast, re
>>> data = '(a (b (c d e f)) g)'
>>> s = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', data)         # quote words
>>> s = re.sub(r'\s+', ',', s)                  # whitespace to comma
>>> s = s.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')   # () -> []
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']], 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

People have suggested their own solutions, but the problem with the code you are using is that `sep` is set to the regex `r','`, which matches a single comma. Like you say, you don't use commas to separate text, you use whitespace. If you replace the default value of `sep` with `r'\s'`, or call the function like `tree_to_list'(a (b (c d e f)) g)', sep=r'\s')`, then it works for me.